# MySQL IFNULL on 4 or 5 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a statement that is:

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(rrp, wholesale) ASC
```

...but I wanted to know if there is a way to have an `IFNULL` statement that checks 3 or 4 or 5 columns? All from the same table.

Comment: There is `COALESCE()` function but not sure if it will fit your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

e.g:

```
SELECT ....
  FROM ....
ORDER BY COALESCE(rrp, wholesale, column3, column4)
```

Comment: +1: It's ANSI too, and widely supported on other databases -- unlike `IFNULL`

Comment: My query is ORDER BY COALESCE(rrp, whole_sale, dealer_rate, shipper_rate) ASC but it now returns no results. Wholesale and dealer_rate are null but rrp and shipper_rate have a value. I am using MySQL 5 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You could chain them up, so the expression picks the *first* not-null value from a list of columns:

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(IFNULL(IFNULL(rrp, wholesale), some_column), some_other_column) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `COALESCE`; it may give you what you need.